# How to deploy a GNU GPL software with Java Web Start?

Tags: licensing, gpl

I deploy an interactive software using Java Web Start. This is a quiet useful deployment technology and I don't want to change. Besides I am about to publish my software under a GNU GPL license.

Usually, when a user installs a new software he is asked to read the license terms and accept it. Is there any equivalent process with Java Web Start ? How can I ask my user to accept the license terms before using it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Usually, when a user installs a new software he is asked to read the license terms and accept it. Is there any equivalent process with Java Web Start ? How can I ask my user to accept the license terms before using it ?

The GPL is *not* an EULA the end-user needs to accept (e.g. by ticking a check-box). Some software packages that ship with an installer *do this* but it is not necessary (and this probably created a wrong impression and made you asking). All *you* need to ensure (when you distribute your GPL'ed software) is that you pass along the license-text with the software and make clear that you license the software under GPL.

Apart from that, Java Web Start probably is not the best way to distribute FLOSS as of now. I strongly suggest you to file a report/feature request with the Issue-Tracker of that software telling them exactly what you do and what you need. E.g. so that you can *pass licensing information* and more importantly *offer sources* along with the object code loaded by Java Web Start.

See as well:

- [If I embed a GPL 2 Java applet into my web app, do I have to release the web app source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3868431/367456)

Comment: Alternatively, consider letting the user `Desktop#browse()` one or more links in your "About" dialog.

Comment: +1 For "the GPL is not an EULA". Indeed, it's not an "usage" license, so the end user doesn't have to read or accept it. Instead, it is a distribution license. It only takes effect if said user later attempts to redistribute the software to someone else.